# GUI Extension Model and Editor in the same config file

Tags: 2013-sp1, cme, gui-extensions

[According to the documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-0CBD8182-B9C7-4467-8B45-6260749676F1), it is possible for a GUI extension to have both the model and editor in the same configuration file.

However, I am unable to get this to work.

Here is my `Editor.config` file (empty elements removed for brevity):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Configuration
xmlns="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration/Merge"
xmlns:cfg="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration"
xmlns:ext="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions"
xmlns:cmenu="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/extensions/ContextMenu"
xmlns:edt="http://www.sdltridion.com/2009/GUI/Configuration/Merge">
  <resources>
    <cfg:groups>
      <cfg:group name="Customization.Extension" merge="always">
        <cfg:fileset>
          <cfg:file type="style">/Client/css/Extension.css</cfg:file>
          <cfg:file type="script">/Client/js/ExtensionCommand.js</cfg:file>
          <cfg:file type="reference">Customization.Extension.Interface</cfg:file>
        </cfg:fileset>
        <cfg:dependencies>
          <cfg:dependency>Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME</cfg:dependency>
          <cfg:dependency>Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.commands</cfg:dependency>
          <cfg:dependency>Customization.Extension.Services</cfg:dependency>
        </cfg:dependencies>
      </cfg:group>
      <cfg:group name="Customization.Extension.Services" merge="always">
        <cfg:domainmodel name="Customization.Extension.Services">
          <cfg:fileset/>
          <cfg:services>
            <cfg:service type="wcf">/Client/Services/MyService.svc</cfg:service>
          </cfg:services>
        </cfg:domainmodel>
      </cfg:group>
    </cfg:groups>
  </resources>

  <definitionfiles />

  <extensions>
    <ext:editorextensions>
      <ext:editorextension target="CME">
        <ext:ribbontoolbars>
          <ext:add>
            <ext:extension pageid="CreatePage" groupid="TargetingGroup" name="Customization Extension" assignid="ExntensionBtn">
              <ext:command>Customization.Extension.Interface</ext:command>
              <ext:title>Create Thing</ext:title>
              <ext:issmallbutton>false</ext:issmallbutton>
              <ext:dependencies>
                <cfg:dependency>Customization.Extension</cfg:dependency>
              </ext:dependencies>
              <ext:apply>
                <ext:view name="DashboardView">
                  <ext:control id="DashboardToolbar"/>
                </ext:view>
              </ext:apply>
            </ext:extension>
          </ext:add>
        </ext:ribbontoolbars>
      </ext:editorextension>
    </ext:editorextensions>

  </extensions>

  <commands>
    <cfg:commandset id="Customization.Extension.Interface">
      <cfg:command name="Customization.Extension.Interface" implementation="Customization.Extension" />
      <cfg:dependencies>
        <cfg:dependency>Customization.Extension</cfg:dependency>
        <cfg:dependency>Customization.Extension.Services</cfg:dependency>
      </cfg:dependencies>
    </cfg:commandset>
  </commands>

</Configuration>
```

My command is working as I can get it to display "hello" in an alert.

However, when trying to call `Customization.Extension.Services.Hello()` (a simple WCF method). I get *"Customization" is not defined.*

Please note code anonymised to protect the innocent/client.

Anyone got any hints on how to do this?

I have split out my model into a separate project for now but am interested in how this is supposed to work.

Comment: I'm missing your `<ext:modelextensions>` element that you insert below the `<ext:dataextenders>` element?

Comment: Is that required for this to work? I am unsure what would go in there. It's empty in the real config - removed it for brevity here.

Comment: It is mentioned in the documentation, so I guess something would need to go in there for it to work yes, but not sure what ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can include a "Service" call in your Editor UI extension, without configuring a Model extension, I think is what you are trying to achieve.

The configuration part is ok. You need the "Service group" and the dependency in your files group.

What I don't know is if you have included the `Web.Config` part, something like:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Customization.Extension.Services.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="Tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.WebServices.DeveloperBehavior">
        <endpoint name="MyService" address="" behaviorConfiguration="Tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.WebServices.AspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.WebServices.WebHttpBindingConfig" contract="Customization.Extension.Services.IMyService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

(Maybe there are some differences in the namespaces, the name of "MyService" must match your `Services`, and the `contract` attribute must match the interface class where the `ServiceContract` is defined).

Appart from that, the DLL with your service must be placed in the `/bin` directory of `<Tridion>/Web/WebUI/WebRoot/` where all DLLs are placed.